# Why do I have "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" when opening apple maps?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making an app where the user can open apple maps to get directions, The app works perfect on the simulator but when I run It on my iphone 4s (plunged in the computer) and open apple maps via my app my computer shows me "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" , the app still works but I am worried about getting rejected by apple when I submit my app, is this something I should worry about , or is there a way of solving the problem ? I posted my code below in case there is an issue with it

```
let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

let longitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lon"]!).doubleValue

var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

var options = [
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
    MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
]

self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

annotation.coordinate = coordinate

annotation.title = places[activePlace]["name"]

self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)



//now the placemark will have the lat long put in above
var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)

var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = "\(self.view)"

//this line then launches the app 
mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the "Terminated due to Memory Pressure" message is the iPhone 4S only had 512MB of RAM and this is not enough to run the OS, Maps app, and your app. When you launch Maps there is not enough RAM left, and your app is terminated. The Jetsam process in iOS is responsible to terminating apps when there is memory pressure. As long as you aren't getting memory warnings while only running your app, you should be OK.

Specifically you can do the following three things to make sure you are not using too much memory in your app.

- Implement the applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method of your app
  delegate
- Override the didReceiveMemoryWarning method in your custom UIViewController subclass
- Register to receive the UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification notification

Knowing that launching Maps is likely to result in your app being terminated on older hardware, you might take the opportunity to save your app state before you launch Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is running smoothly in Simulator because Simulator uses RAM of your system as memory, which is a lot as compare to the memory which you will get in the physical device, as in your case it is 512 mb only.

As loading only map in your application will not be the reason you are getting this memory, maybe in your previous viewController you are using a lot of memory.Try to debug that which object is getting most of the memory in your app through Instruments and manage that object properly.That will solve memory issue.